# CSS 3 Animations with jQuery append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I want to create something like this: [JQuery Growl Nofitications](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/). Because I am not very experienced with things like this, at first I create div that I append Bootstrap Alert notifications at the top of the page:

```
<div id="notificationDiv" style="position: fixed; width: 90%"></div>
```

And I append to this div notifications:

```
var that = this;
var uniqueId = new Number((new Date()).getTime());
this.messages.push({id: uniqueId, 
                    message: this.createMessage(type, uniqueId, direction, size)});

$("#notificationDiv").append( (this.messages[this.messages.length - 1]).message );

$("#" + this.idPreffix + (uniqueId).toString()).click(function(){
     that.messages.splice(this._findByUniqueId($(this).prop("id").split("_")[1]), 1);
     $(this).remove();
});
setTimeout(function(){
    that.messages.splice(
    that._findByUniqueId($("#" + that.idPreffix + 
                                 (uniqueId).toString()).prop("id").split("_")[1]), 1);
     $("#" + that.idPreffix + (uniqueId).toString()).remove();

}, this.timeout);
```

And that's ok, it works - for example when I click button nofitication appears at the top of the page and is ,,fixed".
I want to animate add/remove notification, then I extend (i don't know if that's way is good) Bootstrap's alert class:

```
.alert{
      -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
      -webkit-animation-name: slide-in;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in{
    from{
         margin-left: 100%;
         width: 300%;
    }
    to{
         margin-left: 0%;
         width: 100%
   }
}
```

To achieve something like I saw in Mozilla Developer Network: [Using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations). I add -webkit- prefix because at first I want to do it for my browser, Opera 24 and as I saw in ["Can I Use: CSS3 Animation"](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) I have to add it.
But it doesn't work, and because I am very new to non-primitive CSS, I have no idea why and how I can improve it. I will be very happy if anybody decides to help me - thank in advance for each answer.

P.S.
Intentionally I don't want to use JQuery animations or things like that - the idea is that it should be as far as I can independent for external libraries like JQuery or Bootstrap (I know that I'm using Bootstrap classes, but it is very-very-very alpha version :) ).

P.S. 2
Alert HTML from console.log:

```
<div id='message_1411159143475' class='alert alert-success' 
     style ='float: left; width: 100%;'> 
    Operacja zakończona sukcesem!
    <i style='margin-left: 5px !important' class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign'></i>
</div>
```

Comment: animation name is slidein

Comment: Could you add the HTML of your alert?

Comment: `animation-duration: 3s; animation-name: slidein;` with -webkit as needed... but should add -moz if you're building anything for multiplatform.

Comment: @CayceK I changed it to slidein but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @THiCE I paste to my post log from console

Comment: Ok that is only a start. I'm not 100% I just wanted to make sure you had that added and correct. If it worked that would of been great. But I'm not sure what else could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know why that's no working - because of my stupidity :)
I had CSS code between `<script type="text/css">...</script>` tags, instead correct tag `<style type="text/css"></style>` - it should be , not  :) 
Now there is another problem - it animates when it shows, but not when it hides - but now it will be much easier to fix. This answer can be closed now.